# Rings without any principal homomorphic images or without any artinian homomorphic images

Tags: ring-theory, modules

A ring $R$ is artinian if it is artinian as an $R$-module and $R$ is principal ideal ring if all its left and right ideals are principal.  We notice that every artinian ring has artinian quotient rings (homomorphic images), ($R/I$), for any ideal $I$.

My problems are the following:  I am looking for examples of rings either without any nonzero principal homomorphic images or without any artinian homomorphic images. That is:

(1) Are there rings without any nonzero principal quotients (no principal homomorphic images)?

(2) Are there rings without any nonzero artinian quotients (no artinian homomorphic images)?

My examples are the following:

(a) Let $D$ be a division ring and $V$ a countably infinite dimensional vector space over $D$.  The ideal $I:=\{a\in \text{End}_D(V):\text{dim}_D(aV)<\infty\}$ is the only proper ideal of $\text{End}_D(V)$.  I think that $\text{End}_D(V)/I$ is never artinian.  Morever, $I$ is the only ideal of $\text{End}_D(V)$.  So $\text{End}_D(V)$ is an example satisfying (2).

However, I do not have an example for (1).  I would like to test as many examples as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works for both.

A left/right principal ideal ring is necessarily left/right Noetherian, and none of your example's nonzero quotients are Noetherian or Artinian.

This is because a von Neumann regular ring is Noetherian if and only if it is semisimple.  Your example (and its nontrivial quotient) are both nonArtinian von Neumann regular rings.

Comment: Thank you! Is is it possible to get other examples other than the one I have given?

Comment: @mariam without using a VNR ring, I’m not sure how easy it is to ensure it’s not a PIR.  I can think of more simple VNR rings that aren’t Artinian, and finite products of those would work, but I don’t have any fundamentally different ideas.  Simple rings that aren’t Noetherian on a side would work.